# Determinate the variable types of variables

Tags: python

```
def math (x,y):
    if x and y == str:
        print(x+y)
        print(x-y)
    else:
        print("Type Number")
math(3,4)
```

I'm using Python and what I'm trying to do is that I want to plus and minus x and y.
If x and y were both numbers then the function will work.
Otherwise, if x or y were not numbers then it will say "Type Number"
But, the program says "Type Number" even though I typed Number.

Comment: @Sujay I don't think that's what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Oh Yeah! I misunderstood the question. OP should use ```if isinstance(x,int) and isinstance(y,int):```

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you can use `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(x,int) and isinstance(y,int):
    print(x+y)
    print(x-y)
else:
    print("Type Number")
```

[More about `isinstance` here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: I didn't know about what isinstance is. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to comparing the variable types of both `x` and `y`, and the statement `if x and y == str:` is not correct.

You may fix it by replacing the line with

`if type(x) is int and type(y) is int:`

Answer (score 0):

What you have now is checking whether `x` is true and `y` is `str` (this is not equivalent to checking whether its type is a string). What you want is probably this:

```
def math(x, y):
    if type(x) == int and type(y) == int:
        print(x + y)
        print(x - y)
    else:
        print('Type Number')

math(3, 4)
```

Here, you're checking the type of `x` and `y` to be an integer.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! Can I ask one more question? What if I want to plus and minus prime number like 12.2 or 3.6? Then can I write the code like type (x) == int or float?

Comment: If you also want to allow `float`s then yes, you can do that, but make sure you put parentheses around **int or float**.